# AppleScript to download files from HTTP server, mutating the URL?

Tags: http, download, applescript

I've never messed with AppleScript so this is only a concept to me. Can this work?

Bungie, the game designer, is hosting a ton of PNGs for Halo Reach in systematically named files and directories.  IE:

http://www.bungie.net/images/reachstats/commendations/onyx/onyx_large_precision_multiplayer.png

Change two instances of the same word, and you generate another version of the image.  Change "onyx" to "iron", "bronze", "silver" or "gold" and you get a corresponding image, like so:

http://www.bungie.net/images/reachstats/commendations/gold/gold_large_precision_multiplayer.png

Would an AppleScript be able to take an input URL, find and change the instances of the words in the URL, and then download the associated file to a directory?  Today is my birthday (Oct 27th! hence the XXVII) and if this will work I would be super excited if someone could make this!

Thanks for all of your kind answers!

Comment: AppleScript is *so* last millenium. There has got to be a better way to do it than that. I certainly forgot everything I knew about AppleScript some 10 years ago and I'm not willing to recall it...

Comment: Since you're on a mac, I'd probably do it with a shell script using wget.

Comment: @seanizer: Applescript still has its uses today. I agree that there are better languages to accomplish this, but your comment really doesn't do much to help the OP's situation.

Comment: @Philip I agree it's no direct help, but I meant it as something like: "I'm willing to help if I don't have to use AppleScript". BTW: JavaScript OSA is a good replacement for AppleScript ( http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/JavaScriptOSA/ ). A lot more powerful and easier to learn.

Comment: @Justin: yes, shell == terminal

Comment: @seanizer: I've looked at JSOSA, but I think a lot of Late Night Software's products have fallen into disrepair that I'm not too keen on starting with a new one of theirs.

Comment: I used it some 6 or 7 years ago to script itunes. The nice part is, if you code defensively, you can use the same script on OS X (JS OSQA) and Windows (WSH JScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
set the destination_file to ((path to desktop as string) & "picture.jpg") as file specification
set thisImageSRC to "http://www.bungie.net/images/reachstats/commendations/gold/gold_large_precision_multiplayer.png"
tell application "URL Access Scripting"
    download thisImageSRC to destination_file replacing yes
end tell
```

String manipulation is done completely with changing Applescript's text item delimiters. So to get the components of the URL into a list, you need to do the following:

```
set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
set theUrlComponents to (every text item of theURL) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
```

Add salt to taste, but I agree with the first commenter that there are better languages to do this. Applescript would be my last choice here.

Comment: AppleScript editor highlights the first line "file specification" and gives me an error message.  Am I supposed to be changing that to something else?

Comment: URL Access Scripting is just a front end for the `curl` command. You should just be able to delete it and have it still work.